# Hacker rank java string regex username

Tags: java, regex

Problem is to identify valid usernames in a series of strings based on these rules.

1.The username can contain alphanumeric characters and/or underscores(_).

2.The username must start with an alphabetic character.

3. 8 ≤ |Username| ≤ 30.

The input and output are already handled for me they just want the regex.

I have "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+${8,30}"

which I believe asks for An alphabetic character of any case at the start of the string followed by Alphanumeric and underscore characters to the end of the string with a minimum of 8 characters and a maximum of 30. This regex works for 5 out of 8 cases. Most of the cases it doesn't work on are very long and I won't post them here but there is one case it doesn't work on that is short simple and perplexing.

"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"

my regex says it is valid and from the rules I think it should be valid. The answer says it is invalid though. from the rules I have stated above am I missing something about why this should be invalid?

Comment: I'm sorry nevermind. I got it 31 characters

Answer (score 4):

The correct regex is

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{7,29}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM8iR1/1) showing that `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab` fails the test.

When you use `${8,30}`, it means *match the end of the string 8 to 30 times*.

My pattern matches the first alpha character and then 7 to 29 letters, digits and underscores (that is 8 to 30 all in all).

Note that you can write it as

```
^[a-zA-Z]\w{7,29}$
```

**NOTE:** In Java, you will have to double the backslashes when declaring the pattern as a Java C string. Also, you do not need a `^` and `$` if you use `.matches()`:

```
Boolean matched = input.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\w{7,29}");
```

Comment: Ah, it is said it is Java in the title.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+${7,29} satisfied all of the cases. Thank you for your reply Wiktor, wouldn't \w allow other non-whitespace characters lie @&*!()^? those are illegal characters per the rules.

Comment: [`\w` is a *word* character shorthand class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html), it matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` *if* you do not specify the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the case insensitive flag instead of listing out the upper- and lowercase alphas?

Comment: @talemyn: There is no real gain from the case-insensitive modifier. In `String.matches()`, the flag should be passed as an inline version, `(?i)`, it is longer than `a-z`. `\w` is already case insensitive.

Comment: Cool . . . just curious.   :)   The bulk of my regex is of the JavaScript variety, so it's a slightly different scenario . . . just wondering what about the Java flavor might be impacting your choice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This expressions passes all the test cases

```
String pattern ="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{7,29}$";
```

Comment: This is a copy of my solution.